# nodejs - installing typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

snippet of the error in node.js command prompt:

```
C:\Windows\System32>npm i -g typescript

npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

What can be done for the error? I have recently purchased a new system. I didn't get this error on the previous system. I am trying to install typescript globally on the laptop.

Comment: pls don't add images to your questions.  Can you edit your question and add the error as a code snippet instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reinstalling Node.js and npm to see if that resolves the issue. There might be some problems with your current installation that's causing the error. If reinstalling doesn't work, you might try running `npm config set strict-ssl false`.

This command sets npm to not require an SSL certificate, which could potentially solve the issue you're encountering. However, please note that this will make your connection less secure, so use it with caution and only if you understand the potential risks involved. You may wish to reactivate strict-ssl again after that.